# Dynamic memory allocation and deallocation MIPS

Tags: mips, dynamic-memory-allocation

MIPS code for dynamic allocation of memory.

I need to write a main program that keeps on waiting in a loop for user’s request through console for allocation/deallocation of memory of a size for a variable with a name, and calls an allocation or a deallocation procedure accordingly. 
The allocation procedure allocates an available chunk (that is, a chunk not allocated to another variable) of memory, and updates it table to indicate which portions of its memory are allocated to which variables, and which portions of memory are still available. When the main program requests the deallocation procedure to free a portion of memory allocated to a variable, the procedure will mark those portions of the memory earlier allocated this variable as free. The allocation and deallocation requests may come from the user in any order, and a possible complication your project needs to handle is the situation where there may not be enough contiguous memory to handle an allocation request through the total free memory areas total up to a value higher than the requested amount.

my assumptions are:
1.  The pool of memory is very limited, say 2048 bytes.
2.  The pool is partitioned into small chunks of equal size (say, 32 bytes each so that in a pool of 2048 bytes there will 64 chunks). 
3.  Though memory requests could come for any size, allocation is always done in the integral number of chunks. That is, if a request for 100 bytes comes, 128 bytes (or 4 chunks) are allocated.

P.S.: I just need an idea to write in the mips.
Please Help!

Comment: Write in C, compile it with a MIPS compiler, then look at the assembler output from the compiler.